# An activity is installed as an application

Tags: android

I just finished my project, and im my phone(simulator too), when i transfer the .apk to the SDCARD and install it, i have my main app and one activity is installed as an app! Why?
Thank you for your response :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml and make sure there is only one activity with this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

You could have copied&pasted those tags by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In the androidmanifest.xml you must have put the

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in both activities

Remove it from the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, i just removed this line, and the problem is solved!

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Thank you :).